# Reading long text in between tags in XML

Tags: java, android, xml, text, long-integer

So I have a XML that I read. I am able to read successfully with no problem when my tags contain this short of items:

```
<Building>
    <location_id>7</location_id>
    <location_name>Enrique Razon Building</location_name>
    <location_description>Land of Sports</location_description>
    <location_icon_name>pink_trees</location_icon_name>
    <location_hasVisited>false</location_hasVisited>
    <building_image>leaves1</building_image>
</Building>
```

However, when I have tags that have long text in between like this...

```
<Building>
    <location_id>8</location_id>
    <location_name>St. Miguel Hall (College of Liberal Arts)</location_name>
    <location_description>
        Dean: Dr. Dominador F. Bombongan, Jr.
        Vice Dean: Dr. Feorillo Petronillo Demeterio III

        Background
        Constructed on 1969, Miguel Hall was named after one of the three Lasallian Brothers-Saints – St. Miguel Francisco Febres Cordero of Ecuador, canonized by the Servant of God Pope John Paul II.
        1st Floor
        CE-Construction Technology and Management (CTM) Research Laboratory / Interdisciplinary Research Room (M101)
        CE-Survey Equipment Room (M102)
        CE-Geotechnical Engineering Laboratory (M103A)
        CE-Hydraulics and Water Resources Laboratory (M103B)
        Construction Technology and Management Laboratory (M104A)
        Center for Microhydro for Rural Electrification CeMTRE (M104B)
        ECE Thesis Room (M104D)
        Transportation Laboratory (M104E)
        Intelligence Systems Laboratory (ISL) (M106)
        Foundry and Welding Area (M107)
        Air conditioning Control Room (M109)
        Mechanical Engineering Lab Coordinators Office (M110)
        M.E. Technicians Office/Stockrom (M111)
        Fuel and Lubrication Lab (M112)
        Lecture Room (M113)
        Water Resource Laboratory/Flow Analysis Laboratory (M114)
        Mechanical Engineering Department (M105-M107, M115)
        Civil Engineering Lab, ECE Thesis Room (M112)
        Electronics and Communications Engineering Department (M116)
        CE-HWR Research Office (M154)
        CE-GTE Research Office (M155)
        CE-Laboratory Development and Coordination Office (M156)
        Power and Thermodynamics Laboratory

        2nd Floor
        BNSCWC ASEAN Literatures Reading Room
        Desktop Laboratory (M204)
        Person in charge: Jay Magoncia
        For Communication Arts and Organization Communication majors
        Houses computer terminals where the students are taught to layout their own print materials.
        Lecture Room (M205-M206)
        Viewing Room of Communications Department (M208)
        Department of Communication (M209)
        Chair: Dr. Maria Angeli H. Diaz
        Bienvenido N. Santos Creative Writing Center (M210)
        Established with the intention of formalizing and implementing the University’s objectives of contributing to the literary development of the country, and improving the literary skills and expertise of La Salle students, faculty and non-teaching staff.
        Radio and Television/Studio Laboratory (M211)
        Technician: Ricardo Macapuno
        Boasts of equipment which will help you in producing your own Radio programs. The Television Lab is equipped with TV cameras used to produce and air TV programs. It also has a blue screen which makes it possible to create special effects on your videos.
        There is also an editing suite inside the lab where you can do non-linear editing for your video projects. This lab however is open only to students enrolled in communication lab courses.
        The Radio and Television Lab may also be used when you have a photo shoot or a video shoot.

        Television Studio (M212)
        The room has various lights, cameras and other equipment that students can use to complete their projects.
        For Communication Arts and Organization Communication majors.
        CLA Dean and Vice Dean’s Office (M214)
        Photography Laboratory (M215)
        Technician: Ferdinand Pascua
        Photography Labs: black and white and colored photography rooms
        Inside the dark room you can enlarge your own black and white photos and process your negatives
        Photography Laboratory and Workshop (M216)
        Technician: Norman Loteria
        FULLY FUNCTIONAL
        Equipment Room (M217)
        Technician: Edgar Sta. Ana
        Equipped with SLR cameras and tripods which student’s can borrow
        Center for Educational Multimedia (CREM) (M218-M219)
        Training for educational multimedia, printing and scanning services for faculty
        Video Production Workshop (M220, M221)
        Video Editing Bay: Norman Loteria
        This room houses about 20 TV’s and VHS players to facilitate linear editing.
        It also serves as a viewing room for classes.

        3rd Floor
        Custodial Room (M302)
        Faculty Dining Room (M301)
        The Phinma E-Classroom (M306)
        Donated by PHINMA Group of Companies and Mariposa Foundation Inc.
        Inaugurated on Nov. 21, 2002, this state-of-the-art classroom is designed with videoconferencing to develop the students’ exposure with other foreign and local students and technology.
        Nursery School (M312)
        Lecture Rooms (M308, M310-M311, M313-M321)

        4th Floor
        Chemistry Laboratory and Lecture Room (M404)
        Electrical Machine Laboratory (M406A)
        Electric Circuit Laboratory (M406B-M406C)
        IMS Viewing Room (M410)
        90 seat capacity
        Boasta of a video projection-VHS format with data converter, overhead projection, opaque projection, slide projection, public address system, Yamaha home theater sound system
        Product Design and Development Laboratory (M413)
        Robotics and Automation Laboratory (M416)
        Lecture Rooms (M417-M421)

        Trivia
        - Formerly known as the St. Benilde Hall and before the split of the College of Arts and Sciences, Miguel Building was part of the College of Engineering.
        - The first computers ever used in DLSU was situated in the Miguel Building – punch cards and yellow paper tape.
        - The Comm Arts Television Studio was a gift of the Japanese people through the Commemorative Association for the Japan World Exposition.
        - Houses some labs for the College of engineering because it was an engineering building before and the equipment are too heavy to transfer to Velasco Hall so they retained the labs.
    </location_description>
    <location_icon_name>pink_trees</location_icon_name>
    <location_hasVisited>false</location_hasVisited>
    <building_image>pattern1</building_image>
</Building>
```

My code fails, the parser doesn't read the entire thing and stops somewhere around the third line in location_description.

Is there a way to make my parser read ALL of the text inside? This is my parser as of the moment:

```
public static Building[] getBuildings(Context ctxt) {
    XmlPullParserFactory factory;
    ArrayList<Building> buildings = new ArrayList<>();
    Building currBuilding = null;
    String currText = "";
    try {

        //Get our factory and pull parser
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        // Open up InputStream and Reader of our file.
        AssetManager assetManager = ctxt.getAssets();
        InputStream fis = assetManager.open("Buildings.xml");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        //point parser to our file
        xpp.setInput(reader);

        //get initial eventType
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

        //loop until end of event
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            // Get the current tag
            String tagname = xpp.getName();

            // React to different event types appropriately
            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_BUILDING)) {
                        // If we are starting a new <Building> block we need
                        //a new StackSite object to represent it
                        currBuilding = new Building();
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    //grab the current text so we can use it in END_TAG event
                    currText = xpp.getText();
                    Log.e("TAG", currText);
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_BUILDING)) {
                        // if </Building> then we are done with current Building
                        // add it to the list.
                        buildings.add(currBuilding);
                    } else if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_LOCATION_ID)){
                        currBuilding.setLocId(Integer.parseInt(currText));
                    }
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_LOCATION_NAME)) {
                        // if </location_name> use setName() on currBuilding
                        currBuilding.setName(currText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_LOCATION_DESCRIPTION)) {
                        // if </location_description> use setDescription() on currBuilding
                        currBuilding.setDescription(currText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_LOCATION_ICON_NAME)) {
                        // if </location_icon_name> use setIconName() on currBuilding
                        currBuilding.setIconName(currText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_LOCATION_HASVISITED)) {
                        // if </location_hasVisited> use setHasVisited() on currBuilding
                        if(currText.contentEquals("true"))
                        {
                            currBuilding.setHasVisited(true);
                        }
                        else currBuilding.setHasVisited(false);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_BUILDING_MAP_IMAGE)) {
                        currBuilding.setMapImage(currText);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            //move on to next iteration
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return buildings.toArray(new Building[buildings.size()]);
}
```

Thank you for reading this post! And thank you for your help!!! :)
EDIT: replaced '&' with 'and', WORKING!!! I just didn't check properly sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that the parser is not reading the '&' in the text correctly? These should probably be encoded...

Replace '&' with `&#038;`

Comment: Hello, I replaced ALL '&' with 'and', the item is still not being parsed. I do believe that the code is too long.

Comment: If it were too long the API should mention a bit limit for getText(). The solution would be to call getText in a loop until next tag is found, but I doubt that is what is going on.. Tried removing the (double) linebreaks?

Comment: Hello, it's me again. This solution worked! I just didn't check properly. Sorry!!! And Thank you so much @Nish!!!